# Unexpected behaviour in Schematron checks

Tags: xml, xsd, schematron

i have the following checks

```
<iso:pattern id="myChecks">
  <iso:rule context="/root/outerElement/innerElement">
    <iso:assert test="typeElement[@someAttribute='type1']">
      No typeElement with someAttribute=type1 found
    </iso:assert>  
    <iso:assert test=".[child::typeElement[@someAttribute='value1']]/data">
      No dataElement found in an innerElement with typeElement with someAttribute=type1
    </iso:assert>
    <iso:assert test="count(typeElement[@someAttribute='type1'] > 1)">
      There is more than 1 innerElement with typeElement 1 with someAttribute=type1
    </iso:assert>
  </iso:rule>
</iso:pattern>
```

and the Document looks like this:

```
<outerElement>
  <!-- 1 of the dataElements is mandatory -->
  <!-- and i need exact one innerElement which has a typeElement with someAttribute=type1 -->
  <innerElement>
    <dataElement>data</dataElement>
    <dataElement>data</dataElement>
    <typeElement someAttribute="type1"></typeElement>    
  </innerElement>

  <!-- This is not allowed and check 3 should find this -->
  <innerElement>
    <dataElement>data</dataElement>
    <dataElement>data</dataElement>
    <typeElement someAttribute="type1"></typeElement>    
  </innerElement>

  <!-- This one is valid because type2 has other restrictions -->
  <innerElement>
    <typeElement someAttribute="type2"></typeElement>    
  </innerElement>
</outerElement>
```

The Problem now is that check 1 and 2 take every innerElement check it and produce an error which means if i have 3 times type 2 i get 3 errors each from the first 3 checks. What i want is to ensure that exactly one innerElement has type1 and ensure that this has atleast 1 dataElement while innerElements with type2 are not forced to have a dataElement.

The third check isn't working at all it seems it just throws an error everytime there is more than one innerElement.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem here was that each innerElement is his own context and therefore processed seperatly. 
The solution for this is to remove innerElement from the context and put it into the assert fields.